# PuTTY Windows pywinauto background

Tags: python, python-2.7, pywinauto

I did a script on Windows using PuTTY:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application().Start(cmd_line='C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\putty.exe -l user -pw  **pwd**  -load Proxy_10.153.1.250 '+ ip +'  -ssh')
putty = app.PuTTY

putty.Wait('ready')
time.sleep(7)
cmd1 = "show log   "+ "{ENTER}"
```

This script will be executed for many switchs, but when it is executed, I cannot do other tasks on Windows else script will be interrupted? Is it possible to be executed in background?

Answer (score 2):

You need a proper tool for CLI automation. Just run `subprocess.call('ssh user@host <the rest of cmd>')` or use Paramiko to run remote SSH command.

BTW, pywinauto's code is incomplete, I don't see `.type_keys(cmd1)`. You may try `.send_chars(cmd1)` instead and use `putty.minimize()` first. But `send_chars` is not guaranteed to work with every app (and it's experimental). So you can just try.

Comment: i used type_keys and it works for me, cmd1 is : show logging.if Putty.minimize() we cannot send keys.

Comment: Yes, `type_keys()` won't work for minimized window, but `.send_chars()` may work. Just try.

Comment: i tried the send_chars: it works after minimize but it writes the characters two times !! I dont know why: expl : show logging  -->  sshhooww llooggggiinngg  ?do you know why  ?

Comment: Hmm... That might be a bug. Let me check it a bit later.

Comment: You may try to roll back to pywinauto 0.6.0 so far. It should not contain this bug.